JPQL nested join
I have 3 entities:
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(

    @Id
    var email: String? = null,

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "EMAIL")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "NAME")]
    )
    var roles: Set<Role>? = null

)
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
data class Role(

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "roles_privileges",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "NAME")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "PRIVILEGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "NAME")]
    )
    var privileges: Set<Privilege>? = null

)
@Entity
@Table(name = "privileges")
data class Privilege(

    @Id
    var name: String? = null,
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    var roles: List<Role>? = null

)
And i need to extract all user's privileges
I tried it like this^
    @Query("select p from User u left join fetch u.roles r left join fetch r.privileges p where u.email = :email")
    fun getAllByUserEmail(email: String): Set<Privilege>

But I got the following error:

org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [SqmSetJoin(entity.user.User(u).roles(r))]

Any ideas how to do that correctly?

Try fetching User entity, and then extracting Privileges from User object rather than directly fetching the Privilege using query for User entity. Actually Hibernate can not map this way.
Or
Instead of
"select p from User u left join fetch u.roles r left join fetch r.privileges p where u.email = :email"

Try
SELECT p 
FROM Privilege p 
JOIN p.roles r 
JOIN r.users u 
WHERE u.email = :email


Just remove the 'fetch' join; since you aren't fetching user, you don't really need a fetch join from user to roles or privilege, it should just be a join.
"select p from User u left join u.roles r left join r.privileges p  where u.email = :email"

JPA doesn't support filtering over fetch joins; it requires that the data you get back for an entity not be filtered so that it can be cached and managed data.
